# EF Core 1.1 - How to Add migrations in .net core console

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

There're two projects in my solution as below:

- **Sample.UI**: a dotnet core console project created by "dotnet new".
- **Sample.Infrastruction**: a dotnet core library created by "dotnet new -t lib",  the BlogDbContext is right there.

When I try to run the `dotnet ef --startup-project ..\sample.ui  migrations add InitialDB` in the **Sample.Infrastructure** folder, it raised an error:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.On
>   Configuring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext

The error stack information:

> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DatabaseProviderSelector.SelectServices()
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef1.get_Value()
>
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Vis
>   itScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
>
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
>
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
>
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DesignTimeServicesBuilder.Build(DbContext context)
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)

I have tried to add AddDbContext to fix the issue, but didn't work for me. Maybe I'm not using the built-in DI correctly. I have googled a lot, but most solutions are used for asp.net core rather then dotnet console.

---

For your reference, below is the **Sample.Infrastructure** source code:

```
namespace Sample.Infrastructure
{
    public class BlogDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public BlogDbContext(DbContextOptions<BlogDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        public BlogDbContext()
        {
             //ATT: I also don't understand why ef requires the parameterless constructor
        }

        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<Blog>().HasKey(post => post.Identity);
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample.UI** source code:

```
namespace Sample.UI
{
    public class Program
    {
        static public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
        private static IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            Configuration = builder.Build();

            //setup DI
            _serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddDbContext<BlogDbContext>(o=> o.UseSqlite(Configuration["ConnectionString"]))
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            // PostApplicationService app = new PostApplicationService();
            // var ctx = _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(BlogDbContext)) as BlogDbContext;   
            // app.Inital(ctx);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

I have also tried @Morten's solution, execute the following command in Sample.UI folder. However, I got the exactly same error.

```
dotnet ef --project "C:\SampleDDD\Sample.Infrastructure" --startup-project "C:\SampleDDD\Sample.UI"  migrations add "InitalDB"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid most commons mistakes when doing *EF Core* migration, do the following

1. explicitly write the project parameters in command
   **--startup-project < StartProject >**, Sample.UI in your case
   **--project < ContextProject >**, this is the project where your DBContext leaves, Sample.Infrastructure in your case
2. migrations work with `public default constructor` or `IDbContextFactory` if default is absent.So if using default constructor you'll have to override `OnConfiguring` in your context class, something like

> ```
> public class BlogDbContext: DbContext 
> {
>    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
>    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
>    {
>      string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnName"].ConnectionString;
>      optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connStr);
>    }
> }
> ```

alternativly you can implement `IDbContextFactory` in the same project where your BlogDbContext resides

```
public class YourFactory : IDbContextFactory<BlogDbContext>
{
    public BlogDbContextCreate()
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BlogDbContext>();
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnName"].ConnectionString;
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connStr);

        return new BlogDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @nsb, I like the Factory solution. It will not pollute my BlogDbContext.

Comment: optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(Configuration["ConnectionString"]); doesnt work anymore. please update

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Sample.Infrascruture` as `--project`. Like this:

```
dotnet ef --project "C:\MYPATH\Sample.Infrastructure" --startup-project "C:\MYPATH\Sample.UI" migrations add "TXT"
```

And then run it from the `Sample.UI` project

The same when you do a `database upgrade`

Also, try to set the connectionstring in `BlogDbContext`

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
 {
     optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=.;Database=MYDB;Integrated Security=True");
 }
```

Comment: I have tried your way, but it raised the same error. Did you succeed in doing so?

Comment: @Charley yes, this is the way I do it. I used hours on this problem.

Comment: I have updated the question to include some error stack information. and the feedback about your solution. Can you help me look at it, and please let me know if you need any other information

Comment: @Charley see my updated answer. Also, try to remove your parameterless constructor BlogDbContext

Comment: yeah, this solution can add the migration successfully, but I don't wanna hard coded the DB information in the dbContext, as I hope the   **Sample.UI** to decide which kind of DB will be used, e.g. SqlServer, SQLite, etc